# How to pass Accept header in jQuery .load() function

Tags: jquery, ajax, image

How to pass Accept header in jQuery .load() function as It need to be passed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in an [earlier answer by Jon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7525477/1906307), `load` can't do it by itself. I prefer to use the `headers` option on the `ajax` method rather than `beforeSend`:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http//example.com",
    headers: {
        Accept: "application/whatever" // Use the actual type you need.
    },
    success: function (data) {
        // Put the data into the element you care about.
        $("#foo").html(data);
    },
    error: function (jqXHR) {
        // Put whatever you need to do if the query fails here.
    }
});
```

The end result is the same but if I like saving keystrokes.

Comment: Ok, if I want to replace all the html with head, body, etc., which selector should I use?

Comment: @rcanovas I don't know whether there is an appropriate selector for jQuery to do it but you can use plain JS: `document.documentElement.innerHTML = data`

Answer (score 7):

You need to utilize the `beforeSend` parameter in the [`ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) method, since `load` does not expose this functionality:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://www.server.com/",
    beforeSend: function(jqXHR, settings) {
        jqXHR.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    },
    // You need to manually do the equivalent of "load" here
    success: function(result) {
        $("selector").html(result);
    }
});
```